# First-Time Homebuyer Credit: Did not get my housing tax credit yet. What should I do?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, credit, first-time-home-buyer

I feel that my new accountant has dropped the ball. In doing my taxes, he failed to get me and my wife the new home tax credit.

In looking into it, those who never owned a home were to get $8k back and those who did were to get $6.5k back for buying a home.

We got nothing and our tax credit was rejected by the IRS. Our accountant has since sent them letters and I'm not sure what else, but we gave him power of attorney to deal with the matter.

To this day we still have nothing. Should I dump him and use a new CPA, or let him continue on things? Is this normal?

Comment: Did you follow it up with your accountant as to why nothing's happened?

Comment: I've heard of the credit being rejected for completely incomprehensible reasons before - it may not be your accountant's fault.

Comment: Why was your application for credit rejected?  Did the IRS give a reason?  (For reference, we got our first time credit within a few weeks of filing.)

Comment: i spoke to the irs on the phone and they said it was improperly filed and some check box was not checked correctly. i never had issues with my wizard of an accountant in NY. so this is really ticking me off!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics on what happened to your credit, but if you truly qualify for the credit, it's not too late to get it.  [You can claim it on your 2010 taxes.](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=206291,00.html)

Comment: You could also always file an amended return, and correct the error that the IRS noted.